# MySQL select column length in php (below PHP7)

Tags: php, mysql

How do I get the actual max length of a specified column in php (prior to PHP7)?

For instance, this table:

id - int(11)
name - string(20)

I want in php to select the maximum number of characters that a field can have, like

```
SELECT length(name) from table1
```

and it should then return 20 (since it's the maximum number of characters for that field).

Comment: For technique to use in php7 and higher, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/42003955/2943403

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use `mysql_field_len`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-field-len.php

Comment: Note that this effectively prevents you from using the MySQLi or PDO extensions.

Comment: Why does it prevent those extensions? For me everything freezes, could that be because of MySQLi?

Comment: Apparently this function returns the length in bytes and not characters ([reference](http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=51189&edit=1)). In my case the charset is set as utf8 and a varchar field with the length of 10 is returned as 30 bytes by the "mysql_field_len" function.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [mysql_field_len](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-field-len.php) for a single column or use the [SHOW COLUMNS FROM table](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-columns.html) query in MySQL to get information about all the columns at once.

Answer (score 2):

Just be careful when using mysql_field_len to read columns that are not ints or strings. For example, decimal(6,4) will return 10 from mysql_field_len.

You may wish to use [SHOW COLUMNS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-columns.html) and parse the data, if you need all of the column information.

Answer (score 0):

Please keep in mind that mysql_field_len has been removed in PHP 7.0.0. A good solution will be using [mysql_fetch_lengths](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.lengths.php), to get an array with length of all fields in a result. There are other calls, such as [mysqli_fetch_fields](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-fields.php) or [PDOStatement::getColumnMeta](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.getcolumnmeta.php) which return fully detailed description, including table name, field name, type, length and more.

Comment: Beat you by a few years: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42004076/2943403  I am going to alter the title of this page.  Please transfer your answer to the mentioned page.